# Why is the background color of my google sheet web app not being applied?

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to present this table to users, and I want to set the background to this gradient color. The background was actually previously an image, and it was showing up when that was still the case, but ever since I removed it and replaced it with background-color, no background property has been showing up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

    body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: radial-gradient(circle at 10% 20%, rgb(147, 230, 241) 0%, rgb(145, 192, 241) 45.5%);
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh; /* Sets the body height to 100% of the viewport height */
    }

  
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        olor: #333;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    
    nav {
      padding: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      background-color:  white;
      position: fixed;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .logo h1 span {
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-size: 13px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .logo h1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .table-container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        background-color: radial-gradient(circle at 10% 20%, rgb(147, 230, 241) 0%, rgb(145, 192, 241) 45.5%);
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    
    table {
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto; 
       
    
    th {
        background-color: #006400; /* Dark green background color */
        color: white; /* White font color */
        height: 60px;
    }

    /* Set fixed width for each column in the header row */
    th:nth-child(1),
    td:nth-child(1) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(2),
    td:nth-child(2) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(3),
    td:nth-child(3) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(4),
    td:nth-child(4) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(5),
    td:nth-child(5) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(6),
    td:nth-child(6) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(7),
    td:nth-child(7) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(8),
    td:nth-child(8) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(9),
    td:nth-child(9) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(10),
    td:nth-child(10) {
        width: 20%;
    }
    th:nth-child(11),
    td:nth-child(11) {
        width: 20%;
    }

    /* Responsive Background */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        body {
            background-color: radial-gradient(circle at 10% 20%, rgb(147, 230, 241) 0%, rgb(145, 192, 241) 45.5%);
        }
        
        
        .table-container {
            padding: 10px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>iConsult | <span>Appointment Scheduling System</span></h1>
    </div>
  </nav>
<center>
<div class="header">
    <h2>Academic Advising Queue Dashboard</h2>
</div>

<br>
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <? var tableData = getSheetData(); ?>
        <? for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
          <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <tr>
              <? for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
                <th><?= tableData[i][j] ?></th>
              <? } ?>
            </tr>
          <? } else { ?>
            <tr>
              <? for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
                <td><?= tableData[i][j] ?></td>
              <? } ?>
            </tr>
          <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
    </table>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace background-color with background, and there is a typo in "olor".